# How to loop though HTML and return id values

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am using selenium to navigate to a webpage and store the page source in a variable.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://google.com")

html1 = driver.page_source
```

html1 now contains the page source of `http://google.com`.

My question is How can I return html selectors such as `id="id"` or `name="name"`.

EDIT:

For example:
The webpage I navigated to with selenium has a menu bar with 4 tabs. Each tab has an id element; `id="tab1"`, `id="tab2"`, and so on. I would like to return each id value. So I want `tab1`, `tab2`, so on.

Edit#2:

Another example:
The homepage on my webpage (http://chrisarroyo.me) have several clickable links with ids. I would like to be able to return/print those ids to my console.

So I would like to return the ids for the `Learn More` button and the ids for the links in the footer (`facebookLnk`, `githubLnk`, etc..)

Comment: What do you mean by html selectors? Exactly like the format you have? Like you want a string that says `id="id"` for each element in the dom? Or do you want a css selector like `#id`? Are you only wanting selectors for some items, or for every element in the `html`(yikes!)?

Comment: @mrfreester For example: The webpage I navigated to with selenium has a menu bar with 4 tabs. Each tab has an id element; `id="tab1"`, `id="tab2"`, and so on. I would like to return each id value. So I want `tab1`, `tab2`, so on..

Comment: I think I understand enough to give suggestions, but would need more detail of the `html` to give an answer. Make a css or xpath selector that will return all of your tabs and find those elements with selenium and store those in a variable. Then loop through that list and call `tabElement.get_attribute("id")`

Comment: @mrfreester see my `Edit#2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a list of WebElements that have an ID use:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id]")
```

You can then iterate over that list and use `get_attribute_("id")` to pull out each elements specific ID.

For name, its pretty much the same code. Except change id to name and you're set.

Comment: After adding `elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id]")` and printing `print(elements)` it is printing a long list of these: `element=":wdc:1500518789123"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @stewartm you comment helped.

This ended up giving me the results I was looking for:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://chrisarroyo.me")

id_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id]")

for eachElement in id_elements:
    individual_ids = eachElement.get_attribute("id")
    print(individual_ids)
```

After running the above ^^ the output listed each of the ids on the webpage specified.

output:

```
navbarNavAltMarkup
learnBtn
githubLnk
facebookLnk
linkedinLnk
```

Comment: While this answer has the exact code you used, I'd suggest marking @stewartm's answer as accepted, since this is exactly what he was saying to do when he said "iterate over that list and use `get_attribute_("id")` to pull out each elements specific ID". Cheers :)